OOM on a low use server

Thank you in advance for your time and your help.
I am running a Rocky-Linux on Linode (Dedicated-2CPU,4GB,80GB) for a dozen of very low traffic Wordpress websites.
Install: nginx, php-pfm, MYSQL(percona).
99% of the time everything runs perfectly and the server runs at 17% average with very low I/O use.Suddenly the server jumps at 200% and I/O jumps to the max. This locks the server.
If that happens during the day I have to manually restart the instance to get the server back.If that happens during the night it triggers OOM at some point and the server is back online.From the logs I can see that mysql and php-fpm are using all the memory and the swap.Would you please let me know how I could track what is triggering this issue?

Here is /var/log/messages

NOTE:
Strangly the server did not come back online after mysql was restarted at 05:50 but at 06:10. During these 20 mnutes the server was out of memory, out of swap and with I/O at maximum.



    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: irqbalance invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 577 Comm: irqbalance Kdump: loaded Not tainted 5.14.0-427.28.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Hardware name: Linode Compute Instance, BIOS Not Specified 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Call Trace:
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel:  
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x48 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: dump_header+0x4a/0x201 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: out_of_memory+0xed/0x2e0 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x6e8/0x960 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __alloc_pages+0x21d/0x250
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: folio_alloc+0x17/0x50
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __filemap_get_folio+0x1cd/0x330
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: filemap_fault+0x404/0x700
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? next_uptodate_page+0x160/0x1f0 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? filemap_map_pages+0x2c2/0x540
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __do_fault+0x37/0x1f0
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_read_fault+0xf4/0x1d0 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_pte_missing+0x1a9/0x400 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __handle_mm_fault+0x32b/0x670
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: handle_mm_fault+0xcd/0x290 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_user_addr_fault+0x1b4/0x6a0 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: exc_page_fault+0x62/0x150
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: asm_exc_page_fault+0x22/0x30 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fdb41f019ff 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fdb41f019d5. 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe9682efa0 EFLAGS: 00010293
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007fdb421ba071 RCX: 00007fdb41f019ff
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RDX: 0000000000002551 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 000055a949950da0
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RBP: 000055a949950da0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007cbe4f316748
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: R10: 00007ffe968b6080 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000002
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 00007ffe9682f010 R15: 000055a949953250
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Mem-Info:
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: active_anon:189069 inactive_anon:670850 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:788 inactive_file:2619 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writebac
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 active_anon:756276kB inactive_anon:2683400kB active_file:3236kB inactive_file:10392kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0k
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA free:14688kB boost:0kB min:276kB low:344kB high:412kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:52kB inactive_anon:72kB active_file:0kB inac
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1633 3607 3607 3607
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:38360kB boost:0kB min:30464kB low:38080kB high:45696kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:534672kB inactive_anon:1075248kB act
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 1974 1974 1974 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 Normal free:36564kB boost:0kB min:36836kB low:46044kB high:55252kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:221552kB inactive_anon:1608080kB ac
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (M) 4*8kB (M) 0*16kB 1*32kB (M) 1*64kB (M) 0*128kB 1*256kB (M) 2*512kB (UM) 1*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 3*4096kB (ME) = 14724kB 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 514*4kB (UME) 660*8kB (UME) 697*16kB (UME) 325*32kB (UME) 128*64kB (UME) 15*128kB (UME) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 Normal: 601*4kB (UME) 904*8kB (UME) 681*16kB (UME) 290*32kB (UME) 118*64kB (UME) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3736
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 14048 total pagecache pages
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 3416 pages in swap cache 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Free swap= 16kB
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Total swap = 524284kB
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 1048440 pages RAM
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 111576 pages reserved
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages cma reserved 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Tasks state (memory values in pages):
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [pid] uidtgid total_vmrss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [487] 0 48710944576 102400192-250 systemd-journal
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [503] 0 503 8652 9598304704 -1000 systemd-udevd
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [527] 0 5272295862177824160 -1000 auditd 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [529] 0 529 1947 6453248    64 0 sedispatch 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [572]81 572 2719 6461440192-900 dbus-broker-lau
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [573]81 573 131612245056    64-900 dbus-broker
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [576] 0 57633786 66 172032 6144 0 firewalld
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [577] 0 57719806 9657344    32 0 irqbalance 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [579] 0 579 524133777824320 0 systemd-logind 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [584] 996 58421215 9873728  96 0 chronyd
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [609] 0 60964425787 147456416 0 NetworkManager 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [635] 0 63556242 1975 229376 1184 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [641] 0 641 3950 6473728288 -1000 sshd 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [647] 0 64766152750 143360 3712 0 tuned
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [654] 0 654 2137 6457344160 0 crond
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [656] 0 656761 6449152  32 0 agetty 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [659] 0 659 1403 3249152    32 0 agetty 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [741] 997 741 644422678 208896992 0 polkitd
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [910] 0 9104325852398304160 0 rsyslogd 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1024] 0102472061 1145 135168 2464 0 nginx
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1025] 987102573915 2450 163840 1856 0 nginx
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1026] 987102675300 3643 172032 1856 0 nginx
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1027] 987102773738 1145 135168 2592 0 nginx
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 2085]272085 712599 387474414515282528 0 mysqld 
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19889]1013 198898441230843 466944 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19890]1013 198908441230774 466944 1072 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19891]1013 198918895635281 503808 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19892]1013 198928639632944 483328 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19893]1013 198938178828506 446464 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19894]1013 198947513221937 393216 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19895]1013 198957513221590 393216 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19896]1013 198968987136255 512000 1072 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19897]1013 198978987136293 512000 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19898]1013 198988880835081 503808 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19901]1013 199018617932636 483328 1104 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19903]1013 199037791624386 413696 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19904]1013 199047638122631 401408 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19905]1013 199057638122700 401408 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19908]1013 199087327619681 376832 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19910]1013 199107071617143 356352 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19912]1013 199126918015791 344064 1099 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19913]1013 199136918015828 344064 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19915]1013 199156918015776 344064 1131 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19917]1013 199176610812861 319488 1130 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysqld.service,task=mysqld,pid=20
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 2085 (mysqld) total-vm:2850396kB, anon-rss:1549768kB, file-rss:128kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:27 pgtables:4048kB oom_sco
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
    Aug 13 05:50:28 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully. 
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Finished system activity accounting tool.
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'. 
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 1h 40min 33.515s CPU time.
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 1h 40min 33.515s CPU time.
    Aug 13 05:50:29 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server... 
    Aug 13 05:50:35 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server. 
    
    Aug 13 06:10:39 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: NetworkManager invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 609 Comm: NetworkManager Kdump: loaded Not tainted 5.14.0-427.28.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Hardware name: Linode Compute Instance, BIOS Not Specified 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Call Trace:
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel:  
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x48 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: dump_header+0x4a/0x201 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: out_of_memory+0xed/0x2e0 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x6e8/0x960 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __alloc_pages+0x21d/0x250
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: folio_alloc+0x17/0x50
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __filemap_get_folio+0x1cd/0x330
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: filemap_fault+0x404/0x700
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? next_uptodate_page+0x160/0x1f0 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? filemap_map_pages+0x2c2/0x540
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __do_fault+0x37/0x1f0
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_read_fault+0xf4/0x1d0 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_pte_missing+0x1a9/0x400 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: __handle_mm_fault+0x32b/0x670
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? nohz_balancer_kick+0x31/0x250
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: handle_mm_fault+0xcd/0x290 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: do_user_addr_fault+0x1b4/0x6a0 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: exc_page_fault+0x62/0x150
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: asm_exc_page_fault+0x22/0x30 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RIP: 0033:0x562d9d92db88 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x562d9d92db5e. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffdd177f5d0 EFLAGS: 00010287
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RAX: 0000562d9f7e81d0 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 0000562d9f7e8150
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RDX: 00007ffdd177f5d8 RSI: 0000000000000004 RDI: 0000562d9f7e8150
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: RBP: 0000562d9f87b600 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000562d9f7c5b40
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000562d9f84be78 R12: 0000000000000002
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: R13: 00007ffdd177f5d8 R14: 0000562d9f87b600 R15: 0000562d9f88eb30
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Mem-Info:
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: active_anon:223047 inactive_anon:638209 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:546 inactive_file:3046 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writebac
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 active_anon:892188kB inactive_anon:2552836kB active_file:2184kB inactive_file:12184kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0k
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA free:14692kB boost:0kB min:276kB low:344kB high:412kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:40kB inactive_anon:48kB active_file:0kB inac
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1633 3607 3607 3607
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:38336kB boost:0kB min:30464kB low:38080kB high:45696kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:346324kB inactive_anon:1262948kB act
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 1974 1974 1974 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 Normal free:36252kB boost:0kB min:36836kB low:46044kB high:55252kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:545676kB inactive_anon:1289988kB ac
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (M) 2*8kB (M) 1*16kB (M) 0*32kB 1*64kB (M) 0*128kB 1*256kB (M) 2*512kB (UM) 1*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 3*4096kB (ME) = 14692kB 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 346*4kB (UME) 397*8kB (UME) 628*16kB (UME) 336*32kB (UME) 144*64kB (UME) 31*128kB (UME) 1*256kB (M) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*409
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 Normal: 263*4kB (UE) 652*8kB (UME) 660*16kB (UME) 320*32kB (UME) 120*64kB (UME) 14*128kB (ME) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB =
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 9049 total pagecache pages 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 896 pages in swap cache
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Free swap= 192kB 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Total swap = 524284kB
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 1048440 pages RAM
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 111576 pages reserved
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages cma reserved 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Tasks state (memory values in pages):
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [pid] uidtgid total_vmrss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [487] 0 48710944 96 102400288-250 systemd-journal
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [503] 0 503 8652 6398304736 -1000 systemd-udevd
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [527] 0 52722958 1377824736 -1000 auditd 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [529] 0 529 1947053248  96 0 sedispatch 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [572]81 572 2719 6461440192-900 dbus-broker-lau
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [573]81 573 1316 5845056    96-900 dbus-broker
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [576] 0 57633786 66 172032 6144 0 firewalld
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [577] 0 57719806 6457344    32 0 irqbalance 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [579] 0 579 5241 4977824576 0 systemd-logind 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [584] 996 58421215 3473728128 0 chronyd
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [609] 0 60964425755 147456480 0 NetworkManager 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [635] 0 63556242 1943 229376 1216 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [641] 0 641 3950 3273728320 -1000 sshd 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [647] 0 64766152750 143360 3712 0 tuned
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [654] 0 654 2137 3257344192 0 crond
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [656] 0 656761 6449152  32 0 agetty 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [659] 0 659 1403 3249152    32 0 agetty 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [741] 997 741 644422 32 208896 1664 0 polkitd
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [910] 0 9104325810798304256 0 rsyslogd 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1024] 0102472061281 135168 3360 0 nginx
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1025] 987102573979402 163840 3680 0 nginx
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1026] 987102675300 1051 172032 4192 0 nginx
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [ 1027] 987102773738249 135168 3456 0 nginx
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19889]1013 198899311639554 536576 1289 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19890]1013 198909004435713 512000 1890 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19891]1013 198918902035243 503808 1290 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19892]1013 198929004436381 512000 1227 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19893]1013 198939311639419 536576 1354 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19894]1013 198949362839679 540672 1236 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19895]1013 198959311639369 536576 1232 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19896]1013 198969004036280 512000 1276 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19897]1013 198978901635207 503808 1208 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19898]1013 198988895735148 503808 1284 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19901]1013 199019049236792 516096 1260 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19903]1013 199039313339372 536576 1217 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19904]1013 199049313339605 536576 1219 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19905]1013 199059313339496 536576 1211 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19908]1013 199088948535994 507904 1193 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19910]1013 199108998036367 512000 1195 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19912]1013 199129260439144 532480 1221 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19913]1013 199139049236831 516096 1202 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19915]1013 199158999736347 512000 1180 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19917]1013 199179311639567 536576 1194 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [19959]27 19959 70108481620166297671104 0 mysqld 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20029]1011 200298880535482 503808 1164 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20030]1012 200308504232878 503808 1197 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20035]1012 200356672214156 356352 1165 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20037]1012 2003757904 4747 270336 1170 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20038]1012 2003857392 3621 262144 1170 0 php-fpm
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20040] 0 20040 3993 6761440182 0 crond
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: [20041] 0 20041 386219565536182 0 crond
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysqld.service,task=mysqld,pid=19
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 19959 (mysqld) total-vm:2804336kB, anon-rss:326480kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:27 pgtables:1624kB oom_score
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Finished system activity accounting tool.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 6min 43.637s CPU time.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 6min 43.637s CPU time.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server... 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Created slice User Application Slice.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Started Mark boot as successful after the user session has run 2 minutes.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Started Daily Cleanup of User's Temporary Directories. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Reached target Paths.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Reached target Timers. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Listening on PipeWire PulseAudio.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Listening on PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Starting Create User's Volatile Files and Directories... 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Reached target Sockets.
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Finished Create User's Volatile Files and Directories. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Reached target Basic System. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Reached target Main User Target. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Startup finished in 246ms. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000. 
    Aug 13 06:10:40 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started Session 270 of User user1.
    Aug 13 06:10:45 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
    Aug 13 06:12:58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Starting Mark boot as successful...
    Aug 13 06:12:58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Finished Mark boot as successful.
    Aug 13 06:15:58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Created slice User Background Tasks Slice. 
    Aug 13 06:15:58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Starting Cleanup of User's Temporary Files and Directories...
    Aug 13 06:15:58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[20058]: Finished Cleanup of User's Temporary Files and Directories. 



You did not configure the server.
There's 2 approaches to solving this (you should apply both):

Configure your apps to limit the amount of memory they use (notably php-fpm and mysqld)

Limit the memory overcommit (sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2, sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=25 but you'll need to tune the latter value).



Thanks so much for your answer.
You are correct, I did not configure the server correctly I think.
As soon as I enter "echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory" the system become unresponsive and gives me "-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory" as an error so I have to reboot the instance to bring it back.
Here is /etc/sysctl.conf:
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
vm.swappiness=1
vm.dirty_ratio=20
vm.dirty_background_ratio=10
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs=4000
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=500

Limiting the overcommit is less drastic safety net than defaulting to OOM Killer - you still need to set limits on the apps to ensure it plays nice. The error you got occurred because the host was already struggling for memory when you ran this (try stopping webserver & mysql before running this again - and note that effects only last till next reboot unless you update /etc/syscl.conf).

Here is what I did: sudo systemctl stop nginx php-fpm mysqld && sudo systemctl status nginx php-fpm mysqld. "echo 2 | sudo tee
proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory" which gives 2 as answer
"echo 25 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio" which gives 25 as answer. "sudo systemctl start nginx php-fpm mysqld && sudo systemctl status nginx php-fpm mysqld" which give answer:
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysqld.service" for details.

If I chnage it again for "0" mysql then starts.

Three choices: More RAM / change mysql config / Keep getting wiped out by OOMKiller.

Optimising mysql config is probably the most interesting of the 3 :-). Can you see something to be corrected in the config below? mysql keeps growing in size until it saturates the whole memory and SWAP. Thanks

Here is my.cnf if that can help. I though this would limit mysql but it keeps growing in RAM and SWAP.
[mysqld]

# Data Directory
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Logging
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
#general_log = 1
#general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql_detailed.log
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time = 2

# Buffer Pool Configuration
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M # 70%-80% memory - so 3.57: 2.5=>2.86
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2 # 1 instance per cpu
innodb_redo_log_capacity = 250M # 1/4 buffer_pool_size
innodb_log_buffer_size = 18M # IMPORTANT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 # 0 is faster but less recovery if crash
sync_binlog = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0

# Character Set and Collation
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


# Binary Logging
# disable_log_bin

# Binary Log Expiration
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 172800    # 2 days (60*60*24*2) to avoid filling the HDD
max_binlog_size = 512M # Max size of a binlog file (0.5 G)
binlog_space_limit = 2G ##2G total limit for binlogs in /var/bin/mysql/

# Performance Settings
key_buffer_size=0
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_open_cache=600
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
join_buffer_size=18M # IMPORTANT
thread_stack=512K
tmp_table_size=20M #per session
max_heap_table_size=10M #per session
table_definition_cache=1200
net_buffer_length=8K # Buffer length for TCP/IP and socket communication default 16384  min 1024


# Connection Limits and Timeouts
max_connections=40 # MAXIMUM NUMBER OF USERS CONNECTED php-fpm, terminal mysql request, mysql connections
max_user_connections=30 # MAX CONNECTIONS PER USER
wait_timeout=250 # TIMEOUT IDLE CONNECTIONS OF SERVER TO DB in seconds
interactive_timeout=250 # TIMEOUT IDLE CONNECTION OF USER TO DB in seconds


# Security
secure-log-path = /var/log/mysql/


# Authentication
default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password
#authentication_policy instead=caching_sha2_password


# log_error_suppression_list='MY-013360' # This hids the log error MY-013360

# PID FILE
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# Uncomment and adjust as needed
#validate_password.policy=0
#plugin-load-add=validate_password.so
#validate-password=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
#validate_password.policy=LOW


# Skip DNS resolution
skip-name-resolve

# Thread Pool Size
thread_pool_size = 16

# Individual File Per Table
innodb_file_per_table=1

# DISABLEING STRICT MODE SO THAT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 does not cause issues in DB
sql_mode=""


+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                          key_buffer_size |           0.000 MB |
|                         query_cache_size |           0.000 MB |
|                  innodb_buffer_pool_size |        1024.000 MB |
|          innodb_additional_mem_pool_size |           0.000 MB |
|                   innodb_log_buffer_size |          18.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                              BASE MEMORY |        1042.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                         sort_buffer_size |           2.000 MB |
|                         read_buffer_size |           1.000 MB |
|                     read_rnd_buffer_size |           1.000 MB |
|                         join_buffer_size |          18.000 MB |
|                             thread_stack |           0.500 MB |
|                        binlog_cache_size |           0.031 MB |
|                           tmp_table_size |          20.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                    MEMORY PER CONNECTION |          42.531 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                     Max_used_connections |                  1 |
|                          max_connections |                 40 |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                              TOTAL (MIN) |        1084.531 MB |
|                              TOTAL (MAX) |        2743.250 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+


In case someone runs into the same issue:

Configure mysql for the best using MySQL_Primer and MySQL_Tunner
make sure the php configuration does not log slow queries as this uses MEM and SELINUX is blocking it (without showing any sealert which I do not understand why) which seems to slow things even more.

I just deactivated the following and things seem to go perfectly so far.
;slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
;request_slowlog_timeout = 4s
If someone could enlight me on why SELINUX is blocking ptrace without a notice in sealert I would be very interested.
Thanks
